# How to evaluate employees based on the NPS of their sales?

Tags: statistics, soft-question

Suppose that, as a manager, I am creating a campign to evaluate employees based on the NPS (Net Promoter Score) of their sales - the objective is to reward high perfoming employees. However, due to the different nature of each role, some employees have a lot more sales than others. What is the best way to create a ranking system? The data available is: NPS for each sale for each employee (the value can be null, if the survey has not been answered by the customer).

I thought about using a bayesian ranking system, but I think that it would be unfair to low seeling employees which sell little beacuse of their specific role.

In a more abstract sense, how can I compare samples of varying sizes without skewing the comparison towards bigger or smaller samples?

Comment: If you are ranking  them based on effect of their sales, then you need to compare employees who had the same opportunity to get sales.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are going to have to make a number of value judgements on this. On one hand, people who have to do more selling not only have more opportunities, but also risks and probably stress given they are more customer facing. Generally these roles are also compensated better because. On the other hand, if there is an element of randomness to the number of opportunities, then you will want to address it by some kind of stabilizing so it feels more fair.

---

One approach would be to use a Bayesian model to stabilize the assessment of low vs high volume sellers.

**Selecting a prior and data model**

First, we'll need to figure out a model for the survey response $i$ for employee $j$: $S_{ij}$. For NPS, we really only need to know how likely a customer is to be a promoter vs detractor (or neither). Therefore, we can model $S_{ij}$ with a [Categorical Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categorical_distribution#) taking values in $\{-1,0,+1\}$ with probabilities $p_{-1,j},p_{0,j},p_{+1,j}$.

With this model, the NPS score for employee $j$ will be quantified as:

$$NPS_j = \frac{1}{N_j} \sum_{i=1}^{N_j} S_{ij}$$

Where $S_{ij}$ has the above categorical distribution and $N_j$ is the of customers interviewed for employee $j$.

Given above, we can see that $NPS_j$ will have a [multinomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution) with the same set of probabilities as $S_{ij}$ (much like bernoulli vs binomial).

With our data model in place, we can now think about the Bayesian prior on the probability vector $p_j:= (p_{-1,j},p_{0,j},p_{+1,j})$. An easy and natural/sensible choice is the conjugate prior, which is a [Dirichlet$(\alpha)$ distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution).

This distribution is on the $3-simplex$ and is a distribution of possible assignments for $p_j$. We can take two approaches here:

1. Uniform prior: $\alpha = (1,1,1)$ which basically says that you think any of the weightings are equally likely.
2. Company/cohort average: Estimate $\alpha$ using observed survey response scores $\hat{p_j} $ for the full cohort using something like this [R function](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/compositions/html/fitdirichlet.html)
   $$\hat{p_j} = \left(\frac{N_{-1,j}}{N},\frac{N_{0,j}}{N},\frac{N_{+1,j}}{N}\right)$$

This is a bit of empirical bayes and may feel like double counting but its just to get to a sensible prior.

**Estimating $E[NPS_j]$**

Once you have the above you can estimate the expected NPS for employee j as follows:

$$\widehat{NPS}_j= \frac{N_{+1,j}-N_{-1,j}+\widehat{\alpha_{+1,j}}-\widehat{\alpha_{-1,j}}}{N + ||\widehat{\alpha}||_1}$$

The overall effect is that people with fewer surveys are not as badly affected by any one bad survey; however, as more data/surveys come in, the observed data will dominate the prior since you have better information.